# How to find the basis of this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

I am reviewing linear algebra and I do not remember what to do when this occurs. I am asked to find the basis of the matrix

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    12 & 15 \\
    -10 & 13
\end{bmatrix}
$$

using the eigenvector $\lambda=-2$.

Applying the eigenvector we get the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    14 & 15 \\
    -10 & 15
\end{bmatrix}
$$

But when I row-reduce this matrix, I get the identity matrix. My question is, did I row-reduce incorrectly, or is it okay in this case to not have the bottom row be composed of zeroes? If this is the case, what does it mean?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Should the first entry of your matrix be $-12$?

Comment: The problem is that -2 is NOT an eigenvalue of this matrix!

Comment: With apologies to my old math teacher Mr. Bagwell (probably very badly misquoted): "What do I do when my rook is under threat from the thimble and I'm down to only vowels?"  I have no idea what you're asking here - there's no such thing as "the basis of a matrix."

Comment: a matrix is a represenation of a linear operator w.r.t some basis

Answer (score 0):

The eigenvalues of this matrix are given by setting:

$$\det\begin{pmatrix} 12 - \lambda & 15 \\ -10 & 13 - \lambda \end{pmatrix} = 0 \iff (12-\lambda)(13-\lambda) + 150 = 306 - 25\lambda + \lambda^2 = 0$$
Solving this quadratic gives complex solutions, so the problem arises with the fact that $\lambda = -2$ is not an eigenvalue of this matrix.

Comment: Of course, it is much simpler to observe that $\det\left(\begin{smallmatrix}14&15\\-10&15\end{smallmatrix}\right)\neq0$.